# Array to string conversion error while using foreach in php in joomla article

Tags: php, joomla

```
<?php
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select($db->quoteName(array('ques', 'options')));
    $query->from($db->quoteName('logical_ques'));

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $result = $db->loadRowList();

    print_r($result);

    foreach($result as $key => $value)
    {
        echo " ". $value;
    }
?>
```

Hello everyone, I'm creating a website in Joomla and I want to display some values from the database into the article but not in array form and for this I've used **foreach** but it's giving me Array to string conversion error

Comment: @aldrin27 just added !!!

Comment: It means that `$value` is not actually a string but an array so you must use `print_r()`

Comment: try using `loadObjectlist` instead of `loadRowList`

Answer (score 0):

`$value` seems to be an array. Please check using var_dump. Echoing an array gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

The array_values seems to be array. So create a recursive function to return string from your array. The code should be something like this

```
<?php

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('ques', 'options')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('logical_ques'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadRowList();

print_r($result);

if (is_array($result)) {
    echo arrayToString($result);
} else {
    echo $result;
}

function arrayToString($array)
{ 
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            $res .= arrayToString($value);
        } else {
            $res .= " ". $value;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

?>
```